# filter a variable such that its repr can be parsed by literal_eval

Tags: python, serialization

I would like to *filter* a variable (i.e. remove invalid content) in order for its string representation to be parsable by `ast.literal_eval`. So basically a `filter_literal` function that guaranties the below assertion for any `obj`:

```
safe_obj = filter_literal(obj)
assert ast.literal_eval(repr(safe_obj))==safe_obj
```

I came up with the following function but I am interested if there is a better approach or, otherwise, if I did anything wrong:

```
_literal_types = set([type(None),bool,int,float,long,complex])
def filter_literal(obj, default=None):
    """ return given `obj` with only "literal" types

    The output can be safely converted to string and evaluated using 
    `ast.literal_eval`::

        import ast
        safe_obj = filter_literal(obj)
        assert ast.literal_eval(repr(obj))==safe_obj

    literal types are strings, number, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans and None

    non-literal content are replaced by `default`
    """
    obj_type = type(obj)
    if obj_type in _literal_types:
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj,dict):
        return dict((k,filter_literal(v,default=default)) for k,v in obj.iteritems())
    elif isinstance(obj,list):
        return [filter_literal(v,default=default) for v in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj,tuple):
        return tuple([filter_literal(v,default=default) for v in obj])
    else:
        return default
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious error is that you aren't dealing with strings that aren't dictionary keys:

```
>>> test = {"bar": [1, True, None, "foo"]}
>>> filter_literal(test)
{'bar': [1, True, None, None]}
```

You should add:

```
if isinstance(obj, basestring):
    return obj
```

In terms of deciding whether you've done anything wrong, *test your function*:

```
for test in [{"bar": [1, True, None, "foo"]}, ...]:
    assert ast.literal_eval(repr(filter_literal(test))) == test
```

Define some tests and run this whenever you make changes.
Also, note that you can simplify your recursive calls, e.g.:

```
filter_literal(v, default)
```

and I would move `_literal_types` inside the function:

```
def filter_literal(obj, default=None):
     """docstring."""
    _literal_types = set([type(None), bool, int, float, long, complex])
    ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the detected bug and coding guideline. So, do you think this is the right way to proceed?

Comment: @Juh_ if you want general advice on improving your code or approach, you should take working code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com